# Function that takes integer inputs and returns a string

Tags: c++

I want to create a function that takes in a user given integer and returns a string that declares whether the integer provided is a composite number or a prime.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

test_prime(int n){
    string result;
    if(n % 2 == 0||n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 || n % 7 == 0){
        string s("Composite");
        result = s;
    }
    else{
        string s("Prime");
        result = s;
    }
    return(result);
}


int main(){
    int n;
    string result;
    cout << "Please type any integer";

    cin >> n;

    test_prime(n);

    cout << result;

    return(0);
}
```

I receive the following error related to the returning of the variable "result": "cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}' to 'int' in return|"

Comment: You need to tell the compiler that `test_prime` returns a `string`: `std::string test_prime(int n) { /* ... */`

Comment: change `test_prime(int n)` to `auto test_prime(int n)` or `std::string test_prime(int n)`.

Comment: `std::string test_prime(int n)` by default return type is `int` :)

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thank you so much. I chanced the output to be the test_prime(n) instead of the assigned variable result.

Comment: You also forgot `result = test_prime(n);`, else returned result is discarded.

Comment: @KevinKouketsu Would "auto" allow me to return any given data type without specifying what data type would be returned such as std:: string etc.?

Comment: You need an extra test `if(n == 0||n == 0 || n == 0 || n == 0)` then n also is a prime

Comment: @sardinsky yes. the return type is defined by deduction

Comment: Your testing for prime is quite naive or optimistic. What if it is divided by 11?

Comment: @JohanC Good point.

Comment: Normally you'll want C++ functions to return values meaningful to *code* and not necessarily users. A C++ solution here would be to define an `enum` of different number types and return that instead of a string which is really meaningless to C++.

Comment: @tadman for function with name `test_prime()` boolean should be sufficient.

Comment: @Slava What would be a systematic and memory efficient way of determining whether a number is a prime or not?

Comment: @sardinsky that is a million dollars question https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/prime-number

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `string s("Composite"); result = s;` is over-complicated. `result = "Composite";` will work just fine.

Comment: What about the numbers 121, 143 and 169?

Answer (score 1):

There're a couple of problems with your code:

1. You forgot to specify the return type of `test_prime`. If you don't do that it will defaults to `int`. That's what the error message indicates: `"cannot convert 'std::string' to 'int' in return"`. It expects an `int` but you are trying to return a `string`.
2. You don't assign the return value of `test_prime` to `result`. You would end up printing the empty `result` string to the output.
3. The `test_prime` function is incorrect (for example it returns "Composite" for 5). I haven't modified that, just the programming errors.

The corrent program (cleaned it up a little):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string test_prime(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 || n % 7 == 0) {
        return "Composite";
    }
    return "Prime";
}


int main() {
    cout << "Please type any integer: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << test_prime(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code that works.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

std::string test_prime(int n){
    string result;
    if(n % 2 == 0||n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 || n % 7 == 0 || n == 0){
        string s("Composite");
        result = s;
    }
    else{
        string s("Prime");
        result = s;
    }
    return(result);
}


int main(){
    int n;
    string result;
    cout << "Please type any integer ";

    cin >> n;

    cout << test_prime(n);

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Define "works". It prints something, but it does not determine if a number is prime properly.

Comment: This could be trimmed down by just `return "Composite"` instead of the temporary variable.

Comment: @tadman then it could be trimmed down to a single `return` statement. :)